# Load file to an array and make necessary changes to array as per input and save it back to file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below reads the file and stores it to an array
it searches in array for specific username and changes password inside the array
and save the array to a File.

> 1. The first column of the file can be a * or DB name
> 2. I would like to change the password depending on the input

```
* DB_USR    QWERTY   
* DB_MGR    QWERTY
TESTDB10 DB_USR PQRSTUV
TESTDB20 DB_USR QWERTY
TESTDB30 DB_USR QWERTY
```

Below is the code snippet that reads the file into array and searches the array

```
import sys
import logging

def file_to_array():
    file_info="/application/files/Password.txt"
    with open (file_info,'rt') ass fh:
        pw_lines = [x.strip() for x in fh.readlines() if not x.startswith('#')] 

    username="DB_USR"
    pwd="PQRSTUV"

    pw_lines = [re.sub(fr'^(\s*{username}\S+)\s+', fr'\1{pwd}', line) for line in pw_lines]  # This line searches for a value DBFS_USR in 2nd column  and changes the password in 3rd column 
     
def main():   
  file_to_array()
```

I would like the below regex to work in two ways ,

```
pw_lines = [re.sub(fr'^(\b{username}\S+)\s+', fr'\1{pwd}', line) for line in pw_lines]  # This line searches for a value DB_USR in 2nd column  and changes the password in 3rd column
```

> if the input is ./update_pwd TESTDB10 -> This has to change the
> password in the line which starts with TESTDB10

New File:

```
 * DB_USR    QWERTY   
 * DB_MGR    QWERTY
 TESTDB10 DB_USR PQRSTUV.  -> This value should change
 TESTDB20 DB_USR QWERTY
 TESTDB30 DB_USR QWERTY
```

> if the input is just ./update_pwd -> it should change the password in
> the line that starts with  *

New File:

```
 * DB_USR    PQRSTUV    -> This value should change
 * DB_MGR    QWERTY
 TESTDB10 DB_USR QWERTY
 TESTDB20 DB_USR QWERTY
 TESTDB30 DB_USR QWERTY
```

> As of now, the regex is only working for the wildcard line , but doesn't work If I input the db name.

> I would also like to know if storing the file data in array and interpolating it and changing is good approach or is there any better approach than this ?
> I am new to python and please excuse my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for your case it is proper to read the file into memory, perform your operation and write the result back to the file, but you gonna have problem for large files because of memory issue, so we gonna have to modify some stuffs.

```
import sys
import re

def file_to_array(db_name=None):
    file_info="/application/files/Password.txt"
    with open(file_info,'rt') as fh:
        pw_lines = [x.strip() for x in fh.readlines() if not x.startswith('#')]

    username="DB_USR"
    pwd="PQRSTUV"

    edited_lines = []
    for line in pw_lines:
        line_parts = line.split()
        if line_parts[1] == username and (not db_name or line_parts[0] == db_name):
            line_parts[2] = pwd
            edited_lines.append(' '.join(line_parts))
        else:
            edited_lines.append(line)

    with open(file_info, 'wt') as fh:
        for line in edited_lines:
            fh.write(line + '\n')

def main():   
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        db_name = sys.argv[1]
        file_to_array(db_name)
    else:
        file_to_array() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, i ll use this approach

Comment: here , i am just ignoring  the lines that start with # , i will remove the conition 
if not x.startswith('#')